# CSS I want to center a image in a button that is linkable

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button with the discord logo but when I try to add the anchor tag the text goes down a bit and it becomes uncentered.

Is there a way to fix this or a different way I should be approaching this?

**HTML Code:**

```html
    <li class="nav__btn">
      <a href="" class="button" img class ="disc" src="disc.png" width="20"> Join our Discord</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Pleas provide your code, I can't help you with current information in your post

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this to see if it could help out.
https://coder-coder.com/how-to-center-button-with-html-css/

I would assume it would work the same way with an image button. Also try experimenting with div tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your code here: "button" **><** img class.
Better use button tag for this, see example [button with icon](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_icon_buttons.asp).
Also, provide some screenshot what exactly do you need.